# Duplicate transaction entries on setCurrentOrderState in prestashop 1.6.1.18

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have latest 1.6 version (1.6.1.18).

Problem.
1. Order is created
2. Payment module redirects user
3. On success order state is changed

These lines cause problem

```
    echo $order->getOrderPaymentCollection()->count(); // returns 1
    $history = new OrderHistory();
    $history->id_order = $order->id;
    $history->changeIdOrderState($stateId, $order->id);
    echo $order->getOrderPaymentCollection()->count(); // returns 2
```

Other method

```
    echo $order->getOrderPaymentCollection()->count(); // returns 1
    $order->setCurrentState($orderId);
    echo $order->getOrderPaymentCollection()->count(); // returns 2
```

Here is similar problem, but with another module https://github.com/ICEPAY/Prestashop/issues/1

`setCurrentState` created duplicate entries for transactions.

How to avoid this?

Can I change state and update transaction history at once without duplicate entries?

Upon installation no settings of the shop have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. To avoid payment duplicate change:

```
$history->changeIdOrderState($stateId, $order->id);
```

to

```
$history->changeIdOrderState($stateId, $order->id, true);
```

Third parameter 'true' means use existing payment. Lost half day with this problem, then just try to dig in prestashop github source and found this third parameter.